# Erro ao passar um método para outro método. C++

Tags: c++

Sou iniciante em programação e decide me aventurar num projeto com uns amigos, nele preciso que o programa descida qual a ordem da rotina baseado em um fator, estou passando para uma lista encadeada menor para facilitar a organização e ter que lidar com a classe inteira.
Entretanto estou achando problema para passar o método a função. Segue um código exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Txt
{
    string palavra;
    int tam;
public:
    void load(string txt) { palavra = txt; tam = txt.length(); }
    void print() { cout << palavra << endl; };
    int w_tam() { return tam; }
};

class Info2
{
public:
    int tam;
    void (*print)();
};

Info2 redirecionar(Txt txt)
{
    Info2 info;
    info.tam = txt.w_tam();
    info.print = &(txt.print); // aqui acontece um erro
    return info;
}

int main()
{
    Txt A, B;
    A.load("Amor");
    B.load("Bolota");

    Info2 AA, BB;
    AA = redirecionar(A);
    BB = redirecionar(B);

    if (AA.tam > BB.tam)
    {
        AA.print();
    }
    else
    {
        BB.print();
    }
}
```

Uso o VS2017, e o [erro](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2276?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DPT-BR%26k%3Dk(C2276)%26rd%3Dtrue) tem a seguinte descrição:
'&' operação inválida na expressão de função membro associada.
Porém não consegui entender, vi a mesma ideia num outro [tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/como-passar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-como-par%C3%A2metro-em-c) em C.

Comment: Você precisa decidir se quer fazer em C++ ou em C. Este código mistura as duas coisas.

Comment: O tipo do `Txt::print` não é `void (*)()`, e sim `void (Txt::*)()`.

Comment: A ideia seria fazer isso em C++, como faço?

Answer (score 1):

O tipo do `Txt::print` não é `void (*)()`, e sim `void (Txt:: *)()`.

Mude o tipo de `print` na classe `Info2`:

```
class Info2
{
public:
    int tam;
    void (Txt:: *print)();
};
```

E atribua o endereço da função membro:

```
info.print = &Txt::print;
```

Também guarde a instância de um `Txt`, pois uma função membro só pode ser chamada com uma instância válida da classe.

Para chamar a função membro, use o operator `.*` (ou `->*` em caso da instância do `Info2` ser acessível apenas por um ponteiro) junto com a instância de um `Txt`:

```
auto print = AA.print;
(A.*print)(); // Ou (A.*AA.print)();
```

Perceba os parênteses em volta de `A.*print`: a precedência de uma chamada de função é maior que do operador `.*`, então os parênteses são necessários.

Se quiser evitar essa sintaxe e não se importar com alocações dinâmicas, você pode fazer uso de `std::function` para guardar a chamada do método dentro de uma lambda:

```
#include <functional>

class Info2
{
public:
    int tam;
    std::function<void()> print;
};

Info2 redirecionar(Txt &txt)
{
    Info2 info;
    // ...
    info.print = [&txt] { txt.print(); };
    // ...
}

// ..
AA.print();
```

Comment: A ideia no caso seria não fazer uma copia da função e sim fazer referencia a ela, com ela conseguindo referenciar os seus membros (que podem variar) e ela continuar mudando, entretanto apenas com outro nome. É possível ou quebra o encapsulamento?

Comment: Apenas mude a passagem por valor para passagem por referência.