# É possível acessar o endereço de uma função em C?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

É possível acessar o endereço, literalmente, de alguma função e C e também guardar em alguma variável do `main()`, etc.?

```
int f1()
{

}; 

int main()
{ 
    int *ponteiro; 
    ponteiro = &f1; 
    printf("%d\n", ponteiro); return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Tem o exemplo do código?

Comment: Não tenho, mas supondo:

int f1(){};

int main(){
    int *ponteiro;

    ponteiro = &f1;
    
    printf("%d\n", ponteiro);

    return 0;

}

O objetivo seria pegar o endereço da função f1, só que não deu certo. Queria saber se isso é possível.

Comment: Talvez isso possa te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/como-passar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-como-par%C3%A2metro-em-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toda função é um ponteiro implícito, portanto o seu nome já é o seu endereço, basta imprimir o seu conteúdo como um ponteiro (`%p`) que é o endereço.

Ao contrário dos que as pessoas imaginam esses nomes todos chamados identificadores ou símbolos não são coisas soltas, isto é um padrão de projeto comum que determina que esses nomes são maneiras simples e legíveis de acessar um endereço de memória, por isso podemos dizer que elas são sempre [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) (embora tecnicamente algumas delas sejam imutáveis). O nome de uma função nada mais é que uma variável imutável que guarda o endereço da memória onde está o código desta função.

Não precisa fazer essa confusão toda:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1() {}

int main(void) {
    printf("%p, %p, %p, %p", main, printf, scanf, f1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jcqYi8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FunctionAddressc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/FunctionAddress.c).

Quando você usa parênteses, com ou sem [argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101), neste nome está dizendo para o compilador que deseja chamar a função e ele coloca uma instrução de `call` no executável, mas se não usar os parênteses esse nome é usado como um valor como outro qualquer e pode ser um ponteiro, no caso para um código de uma função.