# Como passar uma lista de ponteiros que fazem referências a funções como parâmetro

Tags: c, ponteiro

Tenho uma lista de ponteiros que fazem referência a funções do meu código e preciso passar essa lista como parâmetro para uma função que faz a impressão dos casos:

```
double f00(double x){
  ...
  return x;
}

double f01(double x){
  ...
  return x;
}

void imprimeTeste(int tam, double** ptrsToFunc(?), char** strings){ //Como receber corretamento
  for(int i = tam; i < tam; i++){
    int result = takeRoot(ptrsToFunc[i]);
    printf("%s resultado %d", strings[i], result);
  }
}

int main() {
  char* strings[2] = {"Função 1", "Função 2"};
  double (*ptrsToFunc[2])(double) = {f00, f01};
  imprimeTeste(2, pntsToFunc, strings);
}
```

Reparem que consigo passar para a minha função a `char* strings[2]` e recebo como `char** strings`, mas não sei como montar o cabeçalho da minha função `imprimeTeste` para receber a lista `double (*ptrsToFunc)(double)`.

Comment: Talvez esta outra pergunta com resposta te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/como-passar-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-como-par%c3%a2metro-em-c?rq=1

Comment: No caso dessa resposta ele está passando uma referência a cada função. Se eu quisesse receber uma referência, por exemplo para a minha função `f00`, eu teria um cabeçalho com `double(*f) (double x)` como parâmetro. Mas no caso quero receber uma lista com essas referências, e não apenas uma por vez.

Comment: Mas me surgiu uma ideia e depois vou testar:  `double* (*f) (double x)`.

Comment: Se a ideia que vc teve foi fazer um typedef provavelmente vai dar certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Veja esses exemplos:

### Caso 1:usando um vetor de ponteiros e o tamanho

Declare o vetor assim:

```
    double (*ptrs[])(double) = {f00, f01};
```

E na função assim:

```
void Teste1(int,double (*[])(double));
```

note que já pode até listar os nomes das funções na declaração, se for algo constante.

#### um teste completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double f00(double);
double f01(double);
void Teste1(int,double (*[])(double));

int main(void)
{
    double (*ptrs[])(double) = {f00, f01};
    Teste1(2, ptrs);
    return 0;
}

double f00(double x)
{
    printf("F0(%.1f) chamada\n", x);
    return 42.0;
}

double f01(double x)
{
    printf("F1(%.1f) chamada\n", x);
    return 42.1;
}

void Teste1(int tam, double (*F[])(double))
{
    printf("%d funcoes a chamar\n", tam);
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i += 1)
        printf("Funcao %d retornou %.1f\n", i, F[i]((double)i));
}
```

#### saída

```
2 funcoes a chamar
F0(0.0) chamada
Funcao 0 retornou 42.0
F1(1.0) chamada
Funcao 1 retornou 42.1
```

### Caso 2: um vetor de ponteiros, *NULL-terminated*

Pode ser útil quando vai sempre processar todos os registros, na ordem, como um *batch*.

É mais simples usar um `typedef`, algo assim:

```
typedef double (*Fd_d)(double);
```

E declarar a função com ele

```
void Teste2(Fd_d*);`
```

Nesse caso tem que montar o vetor, como faz o sistema com `main()` e o vetor de argumentos:

```
    Fd_d* vetor = (Fd_d*)malloc(3 * sizeof(Fd_d));
    vetor[0]    = f00;
    vetor[1]    = f01;
    vetor[2]    = NULL;
    Teste2(vetor);
```

#### Um exemplo completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double f00(double);
double f01(double);

typedef double (*Fd_d)(double);
void Teste2(Fd_d*);

int main(void)
{
    printf("\nUsando vetor de ponteiros\n\n");
    Fd_d* vetor = (Fd_d*)malloc(3 * sizeof(Fd_d));
    vetor[0]    = f00;
    vetor[1]    = f01;
    vetor[2]    = NULL;
    Teste2(vetor);
    return 0;
}

double f00(double x)
{
    printf("F0(%.1f) chamada\n", x);
    return 42.0;
}

double f01(double x)
{
    printf("F1(%.1f) chamada\n", x);
    return 42.1;
}

void Teste2(Fd_d* vetor)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (vetor[i] != NULL)
        printf("Funcao %d retornou %.1f\n", i, vetor[i]((double)i)), i ++;
}
```

#### Saida do exemplo

```
Usando vetor de ponteiros

F0(0.0) chamada
Funcao 0 retornou 42.0
F1(1.0) chamada
Funcao 1 retornou 42.1
```

Comment: Obrigado @arfneto funcionou! Utilizei `double (*F[])(double)`  na declaração da minha função!

Comment: Em geral é o mais útil. O vetor de ponteiros em alguns casos é melhor porque o consumo é muito simples, como 1 linha no exemplo. Mas montar o vetor pode demorar